# Restarting a Foreground Service in android

Tags: android, service, foreground

I have a service, which runs in a foreground. I understand that if a Foreground service is killed by the system, it's restarted after the availability of resources.

What I want to know is, if it will be restarted, even if the Foreground Service is manually killed from 'Running Services' section of 'Settings'?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the service to restart after being killed use this method in the service object:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```